# Rails polymorphic association: Restrict allowed classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I want a class to `belong_to` other classes through a polymorphic association.

What is the best way to restrict the association to a specific list of classes?

I am considering using a custom validation method like so, but I don't know if this is really the best idea:

```ruby
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :featureable, polymorphic: true

  validate :featurable_is_of_allowed_class

  FEATURABLE_CLASSES = ["Country", "City", "Store", "Product"]

  def featurable_is_of_allowed_class
    if !FEATURABLE_CLASSES.include? featurable.class.name
      errors.add(:featurable, "class not allowed for association")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: if you are expecting the class to throw an error or some sort when another class has `has_many :features`, it's not possible.

Answer (score 29):

We used this validation (Rails 5) for polymorphic type:

```ruby
ALLOWED_TYPES = %w(Star Planet).freeze

validates :moonable_type, inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_TYPES }
```

Comment: `validates :moonable_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }` is not necessary, because Rails already checks that the moonable record exists.

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell Thanks for letting me know that!

Comment: huh, thoughts on how to allow nil? I guess you would do a custom validation for that?

Comment: @unflores you can use the allow_nil option. 
ex: `validates :size, inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_TYPES }, allow_nil: true`
[Rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil)

Answer (score 0):

Not so long ago I implemented this gem [SafePolymorphic](https://github.com/gogrow-dev/safe_polymorphic).

The benefit to just using a `validates` is that it's more concise, easier to read and you get some helpers like scopes.

```rb
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :featureable, polymorphic: [Country, City, Store, Product]
end
```